# Why don't active contextual action bar when check the checkbox on the listview?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I want to show custom action bar when checkbox checked in listview. I wrote the one xml file type of menu like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:title="actionbar"
        android:icon="@drawable/recycle"/>

</menu>
```

I use for custom listview this codes:

```
private class Adapter_collection extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public Adapter_collection(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
        String[] name_collection_tbl_collection) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, name_collection_tbl_collection);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, parent, false);
    TextView txt_item_list_collection = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView_Item_Listview);
    CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_Item_Listview);

    checkBox.setTag(position);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked ) {   
            if (mActionmode!=null) {
                MyActionModeCallBack callBack = new MyActionModeCallBack();
                mActionmode = startActionMode(callBack);
            }

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), buttonView.getTag().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
        }
    });
    txt_item_list_collection.setText(name_collection_tbl_collection[position]);
    return row;
}
```

}

I add this class for use contextual action bar :

```
    private class MyActionModeCallBack implements ActionMode.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionmode = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now When I check the checkboxes in listview , action bar don't changed . Please advice.

Comment: did you debug the code does the code enter this block checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(){} ?

Comment: I debug now :  mActionmode  is not null therefor don't enter into if statment. I delete if statement and worked .But recycle icon that exist in xml file don't show.

Comment: mActionmode is not null or is it null do clear ?

Comment: I  use  mActionmode = null;    in     onDestroyActionMode method   only.

Comment: I want to ask mActionmode is null or not null here 
if (mActionmode!=null) {...}

Comment: It is null . .......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90949/discussion-between-syed-nazar-muhammad-and-programer138200).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  problem solved with this change :

```
 checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked ) {   

            MyActionModeCallBack callBack = new MyActionModeCallBack();
            mActionmode = startActionMode(callBack);


            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), buttonView.getTag().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
    }
});
```